# Image should link and not the background

Tags: html, css

I need to set a link on a picture. I have to set it up in tables, which I did. But I cannot understand why the picture is linking in full width. That means the background color is also a link. That link should only be on the picture.

If it was a div tag it could be solved with a wrapper, but I do not know how to solve that within tables?

[My Example](http://roulettesuite.com/test.html)

This is my code:

```
<body>
  <table class="wrapper" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td class="wrapper-inner">
        <!-- Row 1 -->
        <table class="row collapse" >
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first">
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <th>
                        <a href="https://www.google.dk/"><img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Z4vZ7AsD6Bc/T_PNRK_9f2I/AAAAAAAAAH4/t3UZ3BQyqdE/s1600/shutterstock.jpg" alt="test" align="center" class="float-center" ></a>
                    </th>
                    <th class="expander"></th>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- Row 2 -->
        <table class="row collapse bgcolor--blue">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th class="small-12 large-12 columns">
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <th>
                          <a href="https://www.google.dk/"><img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/7a40daf7853d830815fb83f79752e94a/tumblr_mz2izkaidT1rfn9zxo4_500.png" alt="Fashion news" align="center" class="float-center"></a>
                      </th>
                      <th class="expander"></th>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Give the parent `th` of the image the `text-align:center` style, then set the image display to `display:inline-block;`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can see that solves the problem. I need to reuse that CSS on 10 different pictures. Is there a nice and clean way I could set that up in external stylesheet? I am trying to learn the BEM at the moment.

Comment: The proper way would be to set a class on the `th`'s that you want to style and then set the css in a stylesheet. Ex. `th.center_this { text-align:center;" } th.center_this a { display:inline-block; }`. HOWEVER, I just looked at your example link again and noticed how you plan to use this code and figured i'd help out a bit more. The proper way for setting up a simple website layout is not with tables. Check out this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0L9op2gt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't notice this should happen. Try this CSS :

```
th {
    text-align: center;
}

th a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**edit** using @SpencerMay comment

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is working if you also set `style="text-align:center;"` on the parent `<th>` tag as @Spencer May suggested. How would you set that up in an external stylesheet? I have to use the same line of code on around 10 pictures. Et the moment I am trying to learn the BEM.

Comment: You can use a <style> element with the above code I gave you.